# How to add a column for displaying small size of img inside backgrid.

Tags: python, django, backgrid

I want to add a column field inside backgrid to display img  and other information related to that user.

```javascript
var columns = [

    { name: "id", label: "Id", cell: "integer",editable: false },

    { name: "active_image", label: "Image", cell: "uri",editable: false },

    { name: "worker_id", label: "Worker", cell: "string",editable: false },

    { name: "city", label: "City", cell: "string",editable: false }

    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to create new image cell type. However, the simplest solution is to extend the basic `Backgrid.Cell`:

```
{
  name: 'active_image',
  label: 'Image',
  editable: false,
  cell: Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    render: function() {
      var src = this.model.get(this.column.get('name'));
      this.$el.html($('<img>').attr('src', src));
      return this;
    }
  })
}
```

The render function here is rather simplified (and not tested), just to give the idea of howto.

Comment: I tried to implement as per your recommendation but its still not working any how thanks for the guide.

Comment: Its working Thank you so much for help {
    name: 'primary_photo',
  label: 'Image',
  editable: false,
  cell: Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    render: function() {
      var src = this.model.get(this.column.get('Image'));
      //this.$el.html($('<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}this.model.get("primary_photo")">').attr('src', src));
      var path = {{MEDIA_URL}}+this.model.get('primary_photo');
      //alert(path);
      this.$el.html($('<img>').attr('src', path));
      return this;
    }
  })
    },